# Узнать ID устройства по сокету (по IP)

Tags: java, сокет, ip

Есть сервер, запущенный на компьютере:

```
ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(...);
...
Socket s = serv.accept();
...
```

На него с определённого устройства устанавливается соединение (сокет). Возможно ли в данном случае узнать 16-значный ID этого устройства? Что-то вроде `mSocket.getDeviceID()`. Может, как-то через IP-адрес это можно вычислить?

---

Устройством является Android телефон. Нужен его ID. Реально ли узнать его не держа сам телефон в руках? Единственное, что делает телефон - отправляет фотографии на сервер в опр. время.

Comment: Под "ID" я подразумеваю похожее на 4794d371bb23fca7

Comment: Если вам нужен просто уникальный id устройства, почему бы не использовать mac адрес?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду [IMEI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMEI)? Насколько знаю, это телефонная штука, она в IP пакеты не включается.

Comment: @avp, нет не imei. ID

Comment: @matrix, огромное спасибо за предложение. Подумаю. А насчёт ID как?

Comment: По поводу Android ID гугл предлагает, например, [это обсуждение на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: @matrix, а как mac-адрес по сокету узнать?

Comment: В рамках протоколов IP mac-адрес за пределы локальной сети (т.е. дальше первого роутера) не уходит. Вы можете узнать его, только если отправитель предоставит его вам в передаваемых прикладных данных

Comment: @avp, вы имеете ввиду можно только так: `Socket mSocket = new Socket(ip, port); ... mSocket_outputStream.write(mac-address);..`?

Comment: Да, что-то в таком духе. Спрашиваете у системы mac интерфейса через который работает сокет и отправляете его.

Comment: @avp, а вместо мака есть какой-либо уникальный идентификатор, который через сокет доступно узнать в моём случае? телефона нет в руках, приложение уже запрограммировано. Уникальный я имею ввиду такой, что будет отличать телефоны друг от друга. Только не IP и не ID телефона.

Comment: Мне это не известно. Впрочем, можете сами посмотреть на форматы пакетов в [разных протоколах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP#.D0.A1.D0.BC._.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.B6.D0.B5). Т.е. на те данные, которые по сети передает система.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Возможно ли в данном случае узнать 16-значный ID этого устройства?

нет, конечно. произвольные данные (к которым относится и какой-то там «идентификатор устройства») могут быть переданы по сети с одного компьютера на другой лишь при активном участии обеих сторон.

т.е., необходимо дополнить обе программы, которые осуществляют описанную вами связь, требуемой функциональностью — возможностью передачи и приёма нужной вам информации.